# $C^0$-limit of volume-preserving maps on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f_k:B_1\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a sequence of injective differentiable volume-preserving maps (i.e. $\mu(f_k(A))=\mu(A)$ for any measurable $A\subset B_1$) that converges uniformly to $f:B_1\rightarrow\mathbb R^n$, where $B_1\subset \mathbb R^n$ is the open unit ball, $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then can we show that $f$ is also volume-preserving? I can prove that $$\mu(f(A))\ge \mu(A)$$ for any measurable set $A$, but the reverse direction is difficult for me.
I ask this question because in p60 of the book "Symplectic Invariants and Hamiltonian Dynamics (2nd edition)" by Hofer and Zehnder, this statement seems to be implicitly used (although the theorem and idea of argument used in that book are correct), and I suspect it, to be honest.
Current progress: if we are given that $f$ is injective, then using a result in algebraic topology (see [Moving of sphere embedding and its interior defined by Jordan-Brouwer separation theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456974/moving-of-sphere-embedding-and-its-interior-defined-by-jordan-brouwer-separation)), we can show that $f_k^{-1}$ converges locally uniformly to $f^{-1}$ on $f(B)$. Then the reverse direction also follows.

Comment: Not sure about the details, but one way to get in trouble in the plane might be if your $f$ ends up mapping the unit circle to a Jordan curve of positive measure, but all your $f_n$ are differentiable (so the image of the unit circle has measure zero).

Comment: I am not sure, but I would expect a counterexample. See however Lemma 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05575.pdf. I must day, I like your questions.

Comment: the dimension $n$ is not the same $n$ of the sequence’s index, is it?

Comment: @PietroMajer Thanks for your comment, I have modified my question.

Comment: @MartinM.W. I agree that this may lead to a counterexample (although the approximation might be very difficult to construct)

Comment: @MartinM.W. If measure preserving diffeo’s $f_n$  map $\mathbb S^2$ to itself,   and the uniform limit $f$ maps the equator to a Jordan curve of positive measure, then $f_n$ on either the North or the South hemisphere should be a counterexample.

Comment: Actually, I also suspect there might be a counterexample. I have added some details to the question.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I see. Actually, I suspect some conditions are lacking in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Are you still interested in the question? Did you answer it? Let me know, because if you haven't answered it I would like to think about it in the next few days. Are you a PhD student at ETH? You can contact me by email.